# Getting a string from in between two words?

Tags: c++

How do you return a string from in between two words? For example:

`STARThello how are you doing today?END`

The output would be:

`hello how are you doing today?`

I've always been curious on how I would be able to do that.

Comment: Is the length of the string fixed?  Are the words `START` and `END` fixed, or can they be anything else like `BEGIN` and `END` as well?

Comment: Nope. START would be where the string would start and then END would be where the string would end.

Comment: Oh, sure! That works, too.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

Assuming you know the lengths of your `"START"` and `"STOP"` to be `5` and `4` respectively,

you can do this:

```
std::string str = "STARThello how are you doing today?END";
const int startSize = 5;  //or perharps something like startString.size()
const int endSize = 4;    //or perharps something like stopString.size()
const int countSize = str.size() - (startSize + endSize);

std::string substring = str.substr(startSize, countSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a good case for std::regex, which is part of C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    auto start = "START"s;
    auto end = "END"s;

    std::regex base_regex(start + "(.*)" + end);

    auto example = "STARThello how are you doing today?END"s;

    std::smatch base_match;
    std::string matched;

    if (std::regex_match(example, base_match, base_regex)) {
        // The first sub_match is the whole string; the next
        // sub_match is the first parenthesized expression.
        if (base_match.size() == 2) {
            matched = base_match[1].str();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "example: \""<<example << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "matched: \""<<matched << "\"\n";

}
```

Prints:

```
example: "STARThello how are you doing today?END"
matched: "hello how are you doing today?"
```

What I did was create a program that creates two strings, `start` and `end` that serve as my start and end matches.  I then use a regular expression string that will look for those, and match against anything in-between (including nothing).  Then I use regex_match to find the matching part of the expression, and set matched as the matched string.

For more info, see
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex
and
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search